# how to get query string with VirtualPathProvider

Tags: asp.net, virtualpathprovider

I am usnig a VirtualPathProvider, but with in the function

```
public bool IsPathVirtual(string virtualPath)
    {}
```

virtualPath give just the URL with out query string
my question is how can i get query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching the solution as easy as this

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
```